Getting "Import "moviepy.editor" could not be resolved" error when trying to import moviepy
I am trying to import moviepy. I installed it with pip in my VSCode Terminal:
pip install moviepy

It seems like everything installed correctly, but with the following code:
from moviepy.editor import *

I get this Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\thoma\OneDrive\Desktop\moviepy\edit.py", line 1, in <module>
    from moviepy.editor import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'moviepy'

I don't know, what to do now.
I am new to programming and stackoverflow, and I am not a native English speaker, so please have leniency.
I already tried installing moviepy manually on GitHub, currently I have it in my program files folder, but I don't know what to do, because I couldn't figure out how to install it in CMD.

Had the same issue. Installed Anaconda and created a conda environment and ran
conda install -c conda-forge moviePy

